# Siri Intent extension not working in existing App

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have integrated Intent Extension for Siri Kit in existing iOS Application. Siri directly opens my Application instead of showing the information which I wanted to show on Siri screen only.

I have referred many sample projects it works fine on that but working when I integrate into my existing App.

Good article will help!

Comment: Did you sort out the issue? Facing the same in my Obj-C project for using Conversation Siri Shortcuts in iOS 13 with Xcode beta 2.

Comment: [INCache cacheableObjectForIdentifier:] Unable to find cacheable object with identifier intents-remote-image-proxy This is the error that I am getting

Comment: Have you implemented only Intents Extension? To show custom UI on intent's response you should implement Intents UI Extension.

Comment: How have you implemented the extension to the existing app?

Comment: SiriKit stopped using Siri Dialog prompts (iOS13.1)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122235

Comment: @Nikhil Have you recieved any solution I am facing same issue?

Comment: @AravindMariappan Have you found any resolution?

Comment: @AravindMariappan Yes I got that. Check my upvote to above comment of YannSteph